# Saving an entry gives a date format error for the entry date

Tags: entry-date

Saving or updating an entry gives an error message "The date you submitted is not valid."
Its on a fresh install of EE 2.9.3 with Publisher 1.6.2 (where Publisher shouldn't be the problem I guess).
I had some extensions installed which most of them are uninstalled now (Event Helper, MX CP Notice, Limitee, single entry)

If I change the entry date "14/4/2015 09:05" to "14-4-2015 09:05" I can save the entry.

I also have not changed any of the config parameters.

I never had this before on EE 2.9.3.

Are there any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Update: Wes Baker [posted](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20929), that there are "official solutions".

In ..../system/expressionengine/libraries/Localize.php around line 283 remove the following block of code:

```
if ( ! empty($date_string) &&
    ! is_numeric($date_string) &&
    @strtotime($date_string) === FALSE)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

And:

Open system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/date/ft.date.php and find this block of code around line 100 and remove it:

```
if (preg_match(’/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2}\b/’, $data))
{
    return lang(‘invalid_date_ambiguous’);
}
```

Now, open up system/expressionengine/libraries/Localize.php and find the _datetime() function around line 289 and add this to the top of the function:

```
// Checking for ambiguous dates but only when we don't have a date
// format.
if ( ! $date_format)
{
    if (preg_match('/\b\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2}\b/', $date_string))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

//

Original Answer:

Two changes seems to fix it in cp, PHP 5.4:

/system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/date/ft.date.php

In function validate, delete lines 100–103:

```
if (preg_match(’/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2}\b/’, $data))
{
return lang(‘invalid_date_ambiguous’);
}
```

/system/expressionengine/libraries/Localize.php

In function _datetime, delete the “Fix for some versions of PHP 5.2 ...”, lines 283–290:

```
if ( ! empty($date_string) &&
! is_numeric($date_string) &&
@strtotime($date_string) === FALSE)
{
return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Head on over to your EE backend. If you go to Admin -> Localization Settings, you should set your default date format, and make sure to hit save to make it updated. It should be set to

```
mm/dd/yy
```

See if that does the trick.

**Edit:** In 2.9.3, it even shows the full four year format, so make sure you set it to

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

Comment: Thanks jchrono-battle
I had to set the localization Settings in My Account to the same as in Admin Localization Settings, both to

mm/dd/yyyy

Compared with 2.9.2 where we have a setting for

dd-mm-yy

we don't have this setting in 2.9.3 anymore. It is replaced with

dd/mm/yyyy. And if you choose that you are in trouble. That looks a bug to me.

Comment: Reported to the Bug Tracker